# How does Doom determine its cosine lookup table from an existing sine lookup table?

Tags: c, kotlin, math

I'm struggling to understand how Chocolate Doom assigns its cosine table. The comments explain that it does a PI/2 shift on the sine table in order to calculate the cosine table, but I don't understand how it's done using C.

Here is Chocolate Doom's original source code in `tables.h` and `tables.c`

```
#define FINEANGLES 8192
const fixed_t finesine[10240] =
{
    25,75,125,175,226,276,326,376,
    ...
}
const fixed_t *finecosine = &finesine[FINEANGLES/4];
```

This is what I'm trying to achieve in Kotlin

```
val fineSine: Array<Fixed_t> = arrayOf(25,75,125,175,226,276,326,376, ...)
val fineCosine: Array<Fixed_t> = arrayOf() // This is where I'm stuck
```

Comment: You can't get the exact effect of the C, in which the two arrays share storage, in Kotlin.  Perhaps the most direct translation would be along the lines of `val fineCosine = fineSine.drop(FINEANGLES / 4)` or (more efficiently but longer) `val fineCosine = fineSine.copyOfRange(FINEANGLES / 4, fineSine.length)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A full circle is 2pi radians. So to offset by pi/2 you need to go a quarter of the way around. So if you have `FINEANGLES` values in the circle, you can offset by `FINEANGLES/4`.

But in order to have access to `FINEANGLES` values in `finecosine` `finesine` needs to have at least `FINEANGLES + FINEANGLES/4` values (assuming there isn't logic to wrap around).

A simplified example:

```c
#define FINEANGLES 4
float finesine[] = {0, 1, 0, -1, 0};
float *finecosine = &finesine[FINEANGLES/4];  // {1, 0, -1, 0}
```

Comment: Ah I see! I get it now. The `finesine` array has a length of 10240, so `8192 + (8192/4)` will equal 10240. So Doom will access the `finesine` array at index 2048 and pass the reference to the `finecosine`. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

A follow-up question to the doom finesine table. As I undertstand the table captures the full 360degrees for sine (and cosine - thats thats why it has 10240 elements in difference to the 8192 elements).

Now my questions is. Wouldn't it be more efficient to only capture the 1st quadrant (90 degrees) in a lookup table and cosequently adjust the sign (+/-) and shift the lookup. For example:

sin(37 deg) = -sin(217 deg) = -cos(127 deg) = cos(307 deg) = (+/-)0.60181502315

So you could either just have 1/4th of the original lookup table size or maybe higher precission with an equally long LUT.

Computationally you add 4 comparions (in which quadrant is the angle), a shift (substraction) and a mult by -1 vs a div by 4 for the cosine.